# how to store the data into different string variables from array at run-time?

Tags: java, php, android

I am executing **`sql query`** in phpmyadmin.

Here I have faculty table in database which has `Fname` and `Fdept` fields.

My PHP file is:-

```
include("configuration.php");
$dept = $_GET['Dept'];

$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Fname from faculty WHERE Fdept = '$dept'");
$data = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $data = $data.$row['Fname'].":";
}
$data1="SUCCESS:".$data;
echo "{'query_result':'$data1'}";
?>
```

So, here I am fetching the faculty names by referring their department..

`query_result` `returns` data of faculty names.

example:

```
query_result:SUCCESS:John:Nishant:Nawaz
```

by that i can split each name using split method.. like:

```
String[] parts = query_result.split(":");
for(int i=0; i<parts.length; i++)
 {
   System.out.println(parts[i]);
 }
```

output :

```
SUCCESS
  John
  Nishant
  Nawaz
```

But how can I assign each name to different string variables, without using index like

```
String a = part[0];
String b = part[1];
String c = part[2];
```

Because query result size will be dynamic and if i use this this there will be a **`ArrayIndexBoundException`** occurs
So, how can I use that data by storing it into different string variable,
by that I can put each variable to `sharedPreferences` and use it in other activities

Comment: You cant. Thats what arrays are for

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says **[you may be at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)**. Learn about [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) with [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4712113/5827005). I recommend `PDO`, which I [wrote a class for](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO) to make it extremely easy, clean, and more secure than using non-parameterized queries. Also, [This article](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison) may help you choose between `MySQLi` and `PDO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to wrap your declared variable name in {} as follows

```
${"prefix" . $i} = part[$i];
```

now your preferred language is ambiguous in this question, but you can't dynamically declare variable names in java, so you're stuck with php if you really want/need this. i don't exactly see what limitations you face with just using an array, but i'm not in your shoes. :)